# user registration page: define variable in php?

Tags: php

this is my user registration page. I wanted to validate the form first before inserting the information to the database and redirecting it into another page. but, when I run the page, this error appears : "Undefined variable: valid". do i need to define it first in php?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>  
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $emailErr = $pwdErr = "";
    $email = $pwd = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      $valid=true;

       if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
         $emailErr = "Please enter your email address";
         $valid=false;
       } else {
         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
       }

       if (empty($_POST["pwd"])) {
         $pwdErr = "Please enter your password";
         $valid=false;
       } else {
         $pwd = test_input($_POST["pwd"]);
       }


    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }

    if($valid){
       header('Location: registerinsert.php');
       exit();
      }
    ?>


    <div class="container" id="contain">
      <form role="form" name="frm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
      <h1 style="font-weight:bold;">Registration</h1>
      <hr></br>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email Address<span class="error"> *</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="" placeholder="Email Address"
              value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 
                echo htmlentities($_POST['email']);  // always filter outputs of external data 
                } ?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          </br></br></br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password<span class="error"> *</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="password1" placeholder="Password"
              value="<?php if(isset($_POST['pwd'])) { 
                echo htmlentities($_POST['pwd']);  // always filter outputs of external data 
                } ?>"><span class="error"><?php echo $pwdErr;?></span>
            </div>
          </div>

            </br></br>
          <button type="submit" name="sub" value="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled>Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">Reset</button>
      </form> 
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this entire copy of the file? If yes, then it looks like you are missing one closing curly bracket.

Comment: Define `$valid` as false at the beginning of your file or `if(isset($valid) && $valid === TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

When programming with PHP you can have your [error reporting](http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting) level set to various levels. Yours is turned up to a level that complains if you use variables that are not set, which is a good thing. This lets you avoid typo errors, where you try to reference a variable with an incorrectly spelt name, etc.

"Undefined variable" means exactly that, it has not been defined. You only set `$valid = true` inside `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` but you never set the default value, so when you do `if ($valid)` it may or may not exist.

That means you are using an undefined variable.

So, either set `$valid = false` higher up to define the variable, or use `if (!empty($valid))` to avoid the error, as this will check if it is defined and if not evaluate to false.

Comment: thank you for the info! i tried the if (!empty($valid)), it worked well. but when i tried the $valid = false set at a higher level, i happen to find errors in my insert page. i guess the two has diferent effects?